# Распарсить XML документ Simple XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Не получается распарсить XML (http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote)
Документ берется нормально, создается объект Simple XML но я немогу выбрать ни одного элемента, делаю так:

```
include 'func.lib.php';
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
//загружаем страничку при помощи функции cURL
$a = getLink('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($a);
echo $xml->resourse[0]->field[2];
```

ничего не выводит, подскажите что делаю не так.

Comment: Однако. Три вопроса "Как распарсить XML" за день - это уже перебор

Answer (score 1):

Может проблема в том что там нет "resourse" ?

```
$xml->resources->resource[0]->field[2]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А еще вот хочу забрать значение поля пишу вот так      print_r($xml->resources->resource[148]->field['price']);  приходит пустое поле

Comment: Вы посмотрите что в массиве `field` какие ключи и какие значения